# How would I make the char # repeat such that it will show the given figure in c?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, nested-loops, cs50

I want to make a program for an exercise in the CS50 course that asks the user to input the height of the figure and then makes a figure that is similar to:

```
       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########
```

considering the user inputs height 8.

I have the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int height;

    do
    {
        height = get_int("Enter The Height: ");
    }
    while (!(2 <= height && height<=8));

    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    {

        for (int column = 1; column <= height; column++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

but it prints this:

```
###
###
###
```

when I give height 3.

I am a beginner in the C language and so won't understand the advanced concepts, so I request a simple explanation, please.

Comment: If you change `column <= height;` to `column <= row;` you'll be one step nearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char c = '#';

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter The Height (0 - exit): " );

        int n;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &n ) != 1 || n <= 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%*c", n - i, c );
            for ( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ) putchar( c );
            putchar( '\n' );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter The Height (0 - exit): 10

         #
        ##
       ###
      ####
     #####
    ######
   #######
  ########
 #########
##########

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 9

        #
       ##
      ###
     ####
    #####
   ######
  #######
 ########
#########

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 8

       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 7

      #
     ##
    ###
   ####
  #####
 ######
#######

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 6

     #
    ##
   ###
  ####
 #####
######

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 5

    #
   ##
  ###
 ####
#####

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 4

   #
  ##
 ###
####

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 3

  #
 ##
###

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 2

 #
##

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 1

#

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 0
```

As for your code then you are always outputting the same number of the symbol `'#'` with no indentations.

```
    for (int column = 1; column <= height; column++)
    {
        printf("#");
    }
```

You can change your loops the following way

```
    for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
    {

        for (int column = 1; column <= height; column++)
        {
            putchar( column < height - row + 1 ? c2 : c1 );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

where `c1` is equal to `'#'` and `c2` is equal to `' '`.

Here is another demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char c1 = '#', c2 = ' ';

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter The Height (0 - exit): " );

        int height;

        if ( scanf( "%d", &height ) != 1 || height <= 0 ) break;

        putchar( '\n' );

        for (int row = 1; row <= height; row++)
        {

            for (int column = 1; column <= height; column++)
            {
                putchar( column < height - row + 1 ? c2 : c1 );
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter The Height (0 - exit): 9

       #
      ##
     ###
    ####
   #####
  ######
 #######
########

Enter The Height (0 - exit): 0
```

Comment: it is a different solution but can you make it through my code ?

Comment: @OmKshirsagar It is not a different solution. It is the only solution because you did not provide any solution.:)

Comment: so there is no way that my code can be modified to give the output?

Comment: @OmKshirsagar I modified your code. What is the problem? Use at least the loops from my demonstration program.

Comment: there is no problem i am satisfied but just wanted to know if there was another way thats all. :)

Comment: @OmKshirsagar following your code you just need to change `printf("#");` with `if (column < height - row) printf("%c", ' '); else printf("%s", '*');`

Comment: @OmKshirsagar Another way is to use one more loop to output spaces before outputting the symbol '#'.

Comment: @OmKshirsagar Sorry, I mean `if (column <= height - row) printf("%c", ' '); else printf("%c", '*');` because you are using base 1

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the solution u gave does not give the required output

Comment: @OmKshirsagar Why? It outputs the pattern.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It was my mistake sorry and Thanks

Comment: @VladfromMoscow can You just explain me the code you gave putchar( column < height - row + 1 ? c2 : c1 ) i mean just this line please coz as I said I m a beginner

Comment: @OmKshirsagar You can substitute this statement for the following statements           if ( column < height - row + 1 )
          {
           putchar( c2 );
          }
          else
          {
           putchar( c1 );
          }

Comment: ok thanks to u and google i understood ? conditions Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Shorter is better.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int height = 5;
    char blocks[height];
    memset(blocks, '#', height);
    for(int i=0; i<height; ++i)
    {
        printf("%*.*s\n", height, i+1, blocks);
    }
    return 0;
}
```